# How can I add Firebase to an Angular 2 typescript app. I dont want to use angularfire?

Tags: typescript, angular, firebase

How can I add Firebase to an Angular 2 typescript app. I dont want to use angularfire?

I have the basic angular2 app and need to get Firebase added to it.

Comment: @muetzerich any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. install firebase - https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html
2. create a service class and import/setup Firebase there - http://octomonkey.com/angular-2-services-with-observables-and-firebase/
3. add your methods to connect to your firebase db.
4. Provide the service to your application.